# What is a difference between inherits and extends of classes?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I was looking for the asnwer long time and i get it a bit complicated. What is a difference between inherits and extends of classes ?

My question was born after reading this [ebook](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/ch4.md#class-inheritance) and i was using `extends` syntax so it maked me wonder.

Extends Classes

```
class A {
    a = 2;

    constructor(x) {
        this.a = x;
    }
}

class B extends A {
}
```

Class Inheritance

```
class A {
    a = 4;

    A(x) {
        a = x;
    }

    drive() {
        output( "A" )
    }
}
class B inherits A {
    drive() {
        inherited:drive()
        output( "B" )
    }
}
```

Can i use `constructor` when `inherits` classes ? or `name constructor` when extend classes ?

What is the differenc when using `super` or `inherited` ?

Can i use `inherited` syntax when extending class ?
I read that `super` is a direct way for the constructor of a child class to reference the constructor of its parent class.

Comment: As far as I'm aware `inherits` is not a keyword in ES6...!?

Comment: There is no mention of `inherits` in the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/)

Comment: *Inheritance* (noun, not keyword) is a **concept**. `extends` (ES6 keyword) is an implementation of that concept. When one class `extends` another, it *inherits* its properties...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`inherits` is not a keyword in ES6. In that place of a `class` declaration, only `extends` is valid, you've got a syntax error.

And neither are `a = 4;` in a class body nor `inherited:drive()`. The book section you found this in even  explicitly states "*Consider this **loose pseudo-code (invented syntax)** for inherited classes*".

Answer (score -1):

**Inheriting** refers to the relationship between a derived class (the child) and the base class (the parent). The derived class can use certain methods and fields within the base class according to accessibility levels

**Extending** is interchangeable with Inheriting and usually is used in java (since the syntax for inheritance in java is the keyword extends. In C#, it is colon :

Comment: The question is about specific ES6 *syntax*.  This does not answer the question.